# Python: Converting a Text File into XLS Spreadsheet

Tags: python, text, xls

i'm practicing python, and my current challenge is to take a text file that just contains words (like a brute force dictionary file) and make a spreadsheet out of it.  I made a csv successfully but not a xls.  Below is what I have so far.  The problem is it isn't looping over the words which are separated by newlines.   I'd attach it if I knew how. It simply puts the number 2 in the spreadsheet about 65000 times.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import xlwt
import os

os.chdir('/sdcard/Scripts')

workbook = xlwt.Workbook('dictionary.xls')

worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Dictionary')

text_file =  open('words.txt', 'r')
in_file = text_file.read()

i = 0

for line in (in_file):
    while i < 65500:
        worksheet.write(i, 0,     line)
        i +=1

workbook.save('dictionary.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the program *is* looping over the words - it's iterating through every line in `in_file`. The problem is that *within* that loop, you are printing to the first 65500 rows with the same line. Then, by the end of that, `i = 65500`, so when you advance to the next line, the condition `i < 65500` is no longer true, so `line` does not get written.

The code you probably want is just removing the while loop:

```
for line in (in_file):
    worksheet.write(i, 0,     line)
    i +=1
```

This way, `i` will increase by one for every line that is read. No need to put another loop in.

Comment: the reason for the while loop is that I was getting Traceback errors and a statement saying xls documents cannot exceed a certain amount of rows ( i think due to a limitation of the file itself).

Comment: yeah. ValueError: row index was 65536, not allowed by .xls format.  So I selected a smaller amount, and it seems to somewhat work.  It is doing it letter by letter.

Comment: I made the dictionary file smaller and made your change and it worked.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that. If you want to put words instead of letters, use `text_file.readlines()` instead of `text_file.read()` - they both create iterable objects, but the former gives you a list of strings and the latter gives you a single string, and trying to iterate through that gives you single characters.